# Updating column based on existing fields

Tags: php, mysql

I created a new fields and I need to update it based on existing fields. Wondering if MYSQL can do this using variables or do I have to use PHP? Since the table is huge (300k+ rows, I assume its best done with a query itself is possible)

Current:

```
+-----+--------+--------------+
| pid |  mfr   |     pnum     |
+-----+--------+--------------+
|     | MCAFEE | HIDYFM-AA-DA |
+-----+--------+--------------+
```

Expected:

```
+-----------------------+--------+--------------+
|          pid          |  mfr   |     pnum     |
+-----------------------+--------+--------------+
| MCAFEE___HIDYFM-AA-DA | MCAFEE | HIDYFM-AA-DA |
+-----------------------+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: That is not a new column, you are just updating an existing column. You can use an UPDATE statement. This would be a one-off update though. If your requirement is more than this then it requires some clarification.

Comment: @AndyG Yes, its a field I created, updated the description.

Comment: As suggested, you can perform a one-off update to update the column to concatenated values from the other columns. If you intend this to happen automatically for new rows you can probably use a before insert trigger. But do you need this *additional* column? You can create a unique index for the two columns and just display the concatenated values when outputting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concatenate the two fields and set to `pid`

```
UPDATE table_name SET pid=CONCAT(mfr,"___",pnum)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by mysql query. like this

```
update  example set pid = concat(mfr ,"__",pnum);
```

where **example** is table name